# How can I insert Files into a zip file using Lua

Tags: file, lua, insert, zip

I am writing a script in Lua 5.1 for use with a game engine (EDGE).

I need my script to copy about 20 files into a .miz file (which is really a zipped folder with a set structure) and navigate that structure and copy those files in from a non-zipped folder on the hard drive.

Because Windows 11 it the future I need to use NanaZip rather than 7z which isn't W11 supported.

However, all the examples I've found are for using LUA to zip up files, not insert non-zipped files INTO a zip file without unzipping it.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Are you allowed to use os.execute or similar? And why do you think 7z doesn't work on win11?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Because Windows 11 it the future I need to use NanaZip rather than 7z which isn't W11 supported."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to @koyaanisqatsi I tried it with 7z. You didn't comment on our question on why 7z should be avoided nor whether you are even allowed to use `os.execute`, but it should provide a good starting point:

```lua
os.execute("7z a yourZip.zip yourFile.png")
```

Where `a` is the flag for `Add`.

See the manual for other flags like compression: https://linux.die.net/man/1/7z

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11 also have `tar` that have the option `r` and `u`

```
D:\temp>tar h
tar(bsdtar): manipulate archive files
First option must be a mode specifier:
  -c Create  -r Add/Replace  -t List  -u Update  -x Extract
Common Options:
  -b #  Use # 512-byte records per I/O block
  -f <filename>  Location of archive (default \\.\tape0)
  -v    Verbose
  -w    Interactive
Create: tar -c [options] [<file> | <dir> | @<archive> | -C <dir> ]
  <file>, <dir>  add these items to archive
  -z, -j, -J, --lzma  Compress archive with gzip/bzip2/xz/lzma
  --format {ustar|pax|cpio|shar}  Select archive format
  --exclude <pattern>  Skip files that match pattern
  -C <dir>  Change to <dir> before processing remaining files
  @<archive>  Add entries from <archive> to output
List: tar -t [options] [<patterns>]
  <patterns>  If specified, list only entries that match
Extract: tar -x [options] [<patterns>]
  <patterns>  If specified, extract only entries that match
  -k    Keep (don't overwrite) existing files
  -m    Don't restore modification times
  -O    Write entries to stdout, don't restore to disk
  -p    Restore permissions (including ACLs, owner, file flags)
bsdtar 3.5.2 - libarchive 3.5.2 zlib/1.2.5.f-ipp bz2lib/1.0.6
```

( Above cmd.exe was opened from Lua with: `os.execute('cmd')` )
You can extract a ZIP with it but not creating one as far as i know.
(`tar -xf archive.zip`)
But is it a Problem for you to use TAR instead of ZIP?

Comment: I cannot extract. I *MUST* insert into a zip file that's named a .miz file. If TAR can do it then that's good, but I need insert it into folders (or even create them inside the .miz file when I insert the files)